# Are there some natural bijections between general Dirichlet series and power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, dirichlet-series

The theory of general Dirichlet series and the theory of power theory have some analogs:

> The abscissa, line and half-plane of convergence of a Dirichlet series
> are analogous to radius, boundary and disk of convergence of a power
> series.([wiki/General_Dirichlet_series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series))

By the Riemanian mapping theorem, the  open unit disc $D$ and open upper half-plane $H$ are
conformally equivalent.
So I wonder if there is a bijective conformal map $\phi:D\to H$ such that any general Dirichlet series on $H$ is pulled back by $\phi$ into a power series on $D$.

A related question is [reduction-of-dirichlet-series-into-power-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719940/reduction-of-dirichlet-series-into-power-series).

Comment: There are also major differences as Dirichlet series have two abscissas of convergence which may be equal but also as far apart as $1$, have various other half planes of convergence like mean, uniform etc, behavior at infinity is known at least horizontally etc; also as complex functions they are not generic like power series which every holomorphic function has, while Dirichlet series are almost periodic functions etc; they have a root theory true (generalized Dirichlet series with arbitrary frequencies) but overall they have lots of differences